# Select operated value by multi columns from MySQL using Model in CI4

Tags: mysql, codeigniter-4, codeigniter-query-builder

I want to get column of operated value with multi columns from MySQL in CI4 project.

Here is what I tried.

There are 3 fields `qty, size, unit_price` in table `products` and I want to get multiplied value of all of these 3 fields.

```
class ProductModel extends Model
{
    protected $allowedFields = ['size', 'qty', 'unit_price'];

    public function getPriceOfOneProduct()
    {
        return $this
            ->select('qty * size * unit_price AS price_of_one_product')
            ->findAll();
    }
}
```

As you can see I'm trying to get a column like this: `qty * size * unit_price`

But it's not indicated in `$allowedFields` so CI4 returns error like this:

```
`Unknown column 'qty * size * unit_price' in 'field list' `
```

Do I must use query builder or is there any solution for this issue?
Please kindly answer my question if you know how to handle this.
Thank you.

Comment: it looks like one of the fields you are using can not be found... can you show your tables structure? use `desc table_name` in mysql and then post in your question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Jorge
I updated my question, and it will be easier to understand.
Let's say there are 3 fields and I want to get multiplied value of three columns.

Comment: try adding parenthesis around the fields `... (qty * size * unit_price) as ...` either that or that and separate the `as` as a different parameter like this: `select('(qty * size * unit_price)', 'price_of_one_product')` been a few years without coding in php...

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
class ProductModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'products';

    public function getPriceOfOneProduct()
    {
        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT (qty * size * unit_price) AS price_of_one_product FROM products');
        return $query->getResult();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Abdulla.
Of course, If I use query builder, I can do it.
But I don't want to use it. Want to get data with Entity class.